# How to make an event driven architecture which uses Finite State Machine workflows and windows services, cloud enabled?

Tags: azure, windows-services, cloud, fsm

I have an existing legacy application which is now having an event driven architecture. It adopts FSM workflows and calling windows services. I am looking for a technology solution to make it cloud enabled.

Comment: Keep looking :-) . No seriously, not sure how we can help. [Azure documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/solutions/) does list all the offerings available and since only you know the characteristics of your software only you can decide what to use. It depends on too many factors. You can take a look at [Event Grid](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/event-grid/) or [Azure Functions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/functions/) as a starter

Comment: If you need State Machine that can function in Cloud, please check my blog, some ideas might help you https://mehmetsalgar.wordpress.com/2022/04/18/a-model-driven-event-sourced-cloud-ready-application-with-akka-finite-state-machine-using-kafka-cassandra-and-elasticsearch/

Answer (score 0):

Unless you use Virtual Machines, you'll need to rewrite the Windows Service functionality.

For the Workflow you can use:

Azure Functions with Durable Functions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to adopt workflows customization using the durable functions?

Comment: what do you mean by customization? It's a workflow defined by your code.

Comment: For different needs (consider departments in a hospital), one can design their own workflows. It might be 'FuncA' calls 'FuncB' calls 'FuncC' for one department and 'FuncA' calls 'FuncB' calls 'FuncB1' calls 'FuncA1' for another department. Pipelines/blocks can be modified/added on demand to create/modify workflow configuration(*.wfd file). Based on the this, the code flow/services are called. For each pipeline and block there is a certain set of settings to invoke the actual code. So my question was is there any way to implement such scenarios.

Comment: I don't know any ready to use service / tool for it. You'll need to code and use some design patterns + reflection to create something on the fly with such flexibility